# firefox cannot access internet ubuntu

Tags: firefox, internet-connection

Ubuntu 12.04 installed and run from VMWare player (as guest os in windows 7).
Firefox cannot connect to internet.

IPV4 settings:
Automatic addresses (DHCP) only.
DNS server as in Windows.

Able to ping DNS server.
Not able to ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: Post output of ifconfig and route -n.
Tell us what connection you use NAT ,Bridged, or host-only in VWplayer settings.

Comment: i can't seem to add this comment after pasting the info....

Answer (score 0):

Have you shared your internet connection with your VMware connection ?

Also have you configured your NAT on VMware..

[Try this Video (how to share internet over VM ware) :](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoEOqYWgKNw)

Comment: hi, i done as in the video still it doesn't work.

Comment: VMWare Network Adapter reads "No internet access" in Windows Network and Sharing Center.<br>What gateway should it be? In my guest os, it's different from my Windows gateway.

Comment: I haven't used a lot of VMware, But all searching is telling me that NAT is used for configuring what you are looking for.